# Android volley https with self-signed ssl certificate and strict client auth

Tags: android, apache, ssl, https, android-volley

Can someone point me to the right direction, how to do self-signed ssl connection with client certificate and key in Volley, when apache server accepts connections, only when the client self-signed SSL certificate and key is passed? As i get, i need to pass two certificates, one is client cert, and one is CA? Or maybe i should pass only client certificate, so apache accepts connection? How should i do that, so the library won't pass an error like "No peer certificate"?
When i go to the site in a browser, i get an error that no certificate passed, so when i connect with cURL client.crt and client.key, i am able to connect.

The apache is configured with server.crt, server.key and ca.crt.

Thank you.